# Navigating to Page in Another Folder in .Net Core

Tags: razor, asp.net-core, navigation, razor-pages

I have a .Net Core application that uses Razor Pages.  Under Pages, I have two top level folders - Prescriptions and Admin.  Under Prescriptions folder, I have some CRUD pages that I scaffolded - namely Create, Index, Edit and Delete.  When I enter the address https://localhost:44344/Prescriptions the program goes to the the Index page in the Prescriptions folder - works fine.

Under the Admin folder, I have a page called Client that has an anchor tag:

```
<a asp-page="./Prescriptions/Index"Add Prescription</a>
```

I am trying to navigate to the page https://localhost:44344/Prescriptions.

I have tried a hundred different versions of this tag including:

```
<a asp-page="Prescriptions"Add Prescription</a>
<a asp-page="/Prescriptions"Add Prescription</a>
```

etc. but am unable to get it to work. Using href with the relative path does not work as well - e.g.  href="/Prescriptions".  What am I missing?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I just tried your part and got it working with the following code.

```
<a asp-page="../Prescription/Index">Prescription</a>
```

Hope it helps!